# How to detect for a MaterializeCSS modal closing?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, modal-dialog, materialize

I have multiple Materialize CSS modals on my site and each one of them has a different search bar. I want the website to detect when a modal is closed so I can reset the value of the search bar. I know how to reset the value, but I am having trouble with detecting a modal closing. What is the simplest JS/jQuery way of doing it?

P.S. There is a lot of code that is interconnected so I didn't attach it here and I think it is not really necessary since this is a general problem, not just with a specific modal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Super easy:

```
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.modal');
    var instances = M.Modal.init(elems,{
      onCloseEnd: function() {
        console.log('Modal closed');
      },
      onOpenEnd: function(){
         console.log('Modal Open');
      }
    });
  });
```

When you initialize the modal, you can pass options (as an object `{}`), and M provides a bunch of useful hooks. If you need to detect a specific modal, you can check the id or any other data using `this`:

```
onOpenEnd: function(){
       console.log(this.id+' Modal Open');
}
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/doughballs/pen/qBqvJrL)

[Docs](https://materializecss.com/modals.html#options).